# How to extract the test method name from a test method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, test-suite

I have various python unitttest methods packed as a TestSuite, and one particular test method looks like e.g.

```
<input.MyTest testMethod=test_simple>
```

It looks like this is a class (the type of this thing is `input.MyTest`) but with an additional attribute(?) testMethod.

How can I extract the name `test_simple` from the attribute `testMethod` (or whatever this is)?

Test code (MyTest.py)

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_simple(self):
       pass
```

Suite code

```
from input import MyTest
suite = test.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(MyTest("test_simple"))
print suite._tests[0]
```

Comment: Show your code, by not showing it, you are making this a lot less easy to answer.

Comment: I'm also wondering about that MyTest and MyClass stuff.  Please elaborate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick perusal of the documentation, you probably want to start with [`test.id()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.id)

> id()
>
> Return a string identifying the specific test case. 
>   This is usually the full name of the test method, including the module and
>   class name.

Comment: @Alex Next time, take a look though the documentation first, you'll probably solve your own issue.